# Multithreading output change every time

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am new to Multi-threading concept.i have written small code to understand how multithreading works.Every time when i run,it shows different output.
Please help me to understand where i am wrong.

```
class Worker {
    private:
        pthread_t thread[5];
        bool stop;
        pthread_mutex_t mutex;
          int tid;
          double stuff;       
        double shared_x;

    public:
        Worker() 
        {
            stop = false;
            if (pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL) != 0)
            {
              cout<<"mutex init failed";
            }

         }
        ~Worker() {
            pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);

        }

        void *run(){
            cout<<"tid   "<<tid<<endl;
            pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
           cout<<"stuff before   "<<this->stuff<<endl;
           shared_x+=this->stuff;
           cout<<"stuff After     "<<this->stuff<<endl;
           cout<<"shared_x    "<<shared_x<<endl;
           pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
            pthread_exit(NULL);
        }
        void join(){
            void *status;
            for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
            {
                         pthread_join(thread[i],NULL);
            }
        }
        static void *run_helper(void* context){
            return ((Worker *)context)->run();
        }
        void stop_thread(){
            stop = true;

        }
        void start_thread(Worker worker){

             for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
            {
                tid=i;
                stuff=i+10;
                int status = pthread_create(&thread[i],NULL,run_helper,this);    
            }
        }
};
    int main(){
    Worker worker;
    worker.start_thread(worker);
    worker.join();
    cout<<"Thread exit"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Output1**

```
   tid   0

  stuff before   10

stuff After     10

shared_x    10

tid   2

stuff before   12

stuff After     12

shared_x    22

tid   2

stuff before   12

stuff After     12

shared_x    34

tid   3

stuff before   13

stuff After     13

shared_x    47

tid   4

stuff before   14

stuff After     14

shared_x    61

Thread exit


<b> output2</b>

tid   0

stuff before   10

stuff After     10

shared_x    10

tid   2

stuff before   12

stuff After     12

shared_x    22

tid   3

stuff before   13

stuff After     13

shared_x    35

tid   4

stuff before   14

stuff After     14

shared_x    49

tid   4

stuff before   14

stuff After     14

shared_x    63

Thread exit
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you're running threads and the for loop at the same time, there is no telling when `tid` and `stuff` will be changed or output. The only thing you have inside a mutex is the summation.

Since they are inside a single object that is given to each thread, they will have whatever value they happen to have at that point. You probably want each thread to have its own state object, then you will not have this issue.

Comment: i should initialized tid within the mutex?

Comment: @InvI Rather the `tid` and `stuff` should be inside separate objects. Now you're running separate threads with a single object, so if you add a mutex, you still won't give them anything separate. You might run them one after another, which is quite pointless when doing multithreading.

Comment: Specifically, Worker should have *one* thread, and you should create five Worker objects.